# Can Nginx be used to balance TCP traffic inside Kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, tcp, load-balancing

My leegacy server uses TCP sockets to serve clients (also inside kubernetes). Clients also run inside the same cluster in which server is.
Can we use NGINX to distribute traffic to server POD instances ? 
If so how ?

Comment: Your cluster is On-Prem or local? Waht version of Kubernetes are you using? How many nodes do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible.The standard Kubernetes Ingress resources assume that all traffic is HTTP-based; they do not cater for the case of basic TCP or UDP load balancing. You need to use the stream-snippets ConfigMap key to embed the required TCP and UDP load-balancing configuration directly into the stream{} block of the NGINX configuration file. Here is the [example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/).

Comment: kube-proxy will do the traffic(TCP) distribution to different PODs.

Comment: Yes do you want to change behavior of kube-proxy? what are you trying to do? Do you want to do weigh based routing etc?

Comment: Yes either kube-proxy behaviour change or some other solution is good.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/09/ipvs-based-in-cluster-load-balancing-deep-dive/

Comment: You can use cilium as alternative of Kube proxy but I don't know  if it has features that you are looking for.https://cilium.io/blog/2019/08/20/cilium-16/

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes `Service` does exactly that. You don't need nginx to do load balancing across pods inside the cluster.

If you want to to weighted distribution of traffic, look at `istio` or `envoy ambassador`.

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/tcp-traffic-shifting/
https://www.getambassador.io/reference/tcpmappings/

Comment: kube-proxy does that but we cannot configure for weighted load balancing. I mean kind of 20% to one pod and 80% to another.

Comment: Ah okay. Please update the question with this detail. You probably can do something by hacking around with nginx. But a better and kubernetes native way to do this would be using something like `istio` or `envoy ambassador` which support weighted distribution of traffic.